# the PUT method does not send messages

Tags: laravel

if necessary, I will also put the controller in check although it seems to 
 me that something is wrong with the method because on the output it shows  me a "no message" error and nothing more

is on a piece of my view and the PUT method

```
{!! Form::model($cattle_inventory, array('route'=> 
['cattle_inventories.update',$cattle_inventory->id,'method'=>'PUT']))!!}
                        <div class="form-group">
                            {!! Form::label('cow_name','Podaj Nazwę krowy') !!} 
                            {!! Form::text('cow_name',null, ['class'=>'form-control']) !!}
                        </div>
```

## Route

```
      Route::resource('cattle_inventories','Cattle_inventoryController')->middleware('verified');
```

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#form-method-spoofing) states:

> HTML forms do not support PUT, PATCH or DELETE actions. So, when defining PUT, PATCH or  DELETE routes that are called from an HTML form, you will need to add a hidden _method field to the form. The value sent with the _method field will be used as the HTTP request method:

```
<form action="/foo/bar" method="POST">
    @method('PUT')
    @csrf
</form>
```

Hence you need to adjust your form as such. `@method('PUT')` simply generates the following HTML:

```
<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT">
```

Comment: yes, but I use laravel collectiv to go the same way?

Comment: I'm not following what you mean, can you rephrase your comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this with Laravel collective

```
{!! Form::open(['route'=>['your.route', $id]]) !!}

    // laravel <=5.5
    {!! Form::hidden('_method', 'PUT') !!} //or {{ method_field('PUT') }}

    //laravel >=5.6
    @method('PUT')

{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Laravel collective [Form model binding](https://github.com/LaravelCollective/docs/blob/5.6/html.md#form-model-binding)

```
{{ Form::model($cattle_inventory, ['route' => ['cattle_inventories.update', $cattle_inventory->id]]) }}
```

Comment: I think it works, but I'm throwing out the error "array_key_exists (): The first argument should be either a string or an integer" but I give the key "$ cattle_inventory-> id" and it looks like this "{!! Form :: model ($ cattle_inventory , array ('route' => ['cattle_inventories.update', $ cattle_inventory-> id])) !!} "

Comment: you can check edited post. it should work as per as documentation.